# Same barcode number entered for my daughter and myself while taking a US visa appointment. Is this a problem?

Tags: visas, usa, applications

I filled separate DS-160 forms for myself and daughter. However while taking visa appointment i mentioned same bar code for my daughter as well as me.
How can I rectify the barcode of my daughter?

I don't want to cancel/reschedule the interview as I have already done once.